# Prevent jQuery datepicker to set date automatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having a fully functional jQuery datepicker displayed inline below an input field.

I'm referencing that field with the setting:

```
altField: "#id_of_field",
```

There are no other settings. Datepicker is loaded with document ready.

My problem is that today's date is set (in the input field) automatically on load of page, disregarding the field's state - no matter if it already has value sent from server or is yet not set.

How do I prevent datepicker from setting a value (by it self) in the input field before the user has clicked any date?

**UPDATE**
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2EYFE/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had hoped for datepicker offering a setting to turn off automatically setting the date, but appearently no.

Here's a working solution, with a mix of the other answers.

I'm storing the field's value in a variable before starting datepicker, and then replacing datepicker's choice of value with the variable.

```
var begin_day_value = $('#event_begin_day').attr('value');

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    altField: "#event_begin_day"
  }).datepicker('setDate', begin_day_value);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2EYFE/5/

Comment: I'm happy to hear it works. If some comments were helpful for you, you can upvote them. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using `setDate` method you can clear input field state this way:

```
$("#myDate").datepicker();
$("#myDate").datepicker('setDate', null);
```

**Edit:** http://jsfiddle.net/2EYFE/4/

Comment: Can you check the fiddle in updated answer, isn't this the result you are looking for?

Comment: That would have been fine if the form is only used on creation, but on edit the stored value would be wiped out with this method.

Comment: Please check the updated fiddle, you can adjust it a bit acording your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Why not using the defaultDate option when you create the datepicker? It's the proper way to set a default value by yourself

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate

```
var myDefaultDate = new Date("October 1, 1975 11:13:00"); // save your default date here

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    altField: "#event_begin_day",
    defaultDate: myDefaultDate
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Datapicker assigns different classes to *selected* and *current* dates. You can either remove the class from *current* date cell or override it:

current date - ui-state-highlight

selected date - ui-state-active

So, for example:

```
$("#your_element").datepicker();
$(".ui-datepicker .ui-state-hihglight").removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
```